# Set white-space to normal on md-option in Angular Material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have some values which are particularly long in an md-select which overflow into ellipses on smaller viewports and therefore cut off important text in both the select list, and when displaying the selected value.

I would like to make them overflow down to two or more lines.

In the inspector,

```
md-option .md-text{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

can be disabled but targeting this same selector does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out before I asked the question but thought I would post anyway in case it helps anyone else save some time.

I added:

```
div.md-text{
    white-space: normal;    
}
```

which targets a generated div inside the md-option element. I am not yet certain that this will not cause errors elsewhere so if anybody has a better solution, please let me know.